# Multiple while loop conditions

Tags: matlab, while-loop

Here is my sample code, made to work out how to get a `while` loop to end when any one of three conditions are satisfied.

I want the code to end when `n = 100`, but it ends at `n = 301`. How can I get this to end at `n=100`?

```
clear all; close all;
n = 0;
R = 0; A = 0; T = 0;    

while (R~=1) || (A~=1) || (T~=1)     
    if n == 100
        R = 1;
    end        
    if n == 200
        A = 1;
    end 
    if n == 300
        T = 1;
    end
    n=n+1;
end
```

Comment: Doesn't it feel like OR & AND are the wrong way around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`||` means or ([with short circuiting](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html#bt_0nai-1)). This means that your loop won't quit until all of the conditions are false.

You want to use AND, which is `&&`. This will mean the loop quits when at least one of the conditions is false.

ALSO (from the comments below):

Currently n will have a value of 101 when the loop finishes (because of the `n=n+1` at the bottom of the loop). If it was important that the value of n was 100, then you could insert a `break` [(info here)](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html) into the `if` body so that the loop quit when n = 100.

Comment: Also might be noteworthy that the loop counter will be at 101 when the abort condition is evaluated as true.

Comment: Seconding sobek: This is only a partial answer. Maybe suggest a `break`?